# Problems with TeX scoping

Tags: counters, scoping

If I use

```
\global\advance\itemno by 1%
\ifnum\itemno=4\the\itemno\fi
```

I get 5.  If I use

```
\global\advance\itemno by 1%
\itemno=\itemno%
\ifnum\itemno=4\the\itemno\fi
```

I get 4 as expected.  Why is this necessary?

Comment: Could you please post a full MWE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example

```
\newcount\itemno
\global\advance\itemno by 1%
\ifnum\itemno=4\the\itemno\fi
```

is interpreted by TeX: `\global\advance\itemno by 1...`

the `\ifnum` is expanded because the number scanning is not finished: `\ifnum\itemno=4...` the `\the\itemno` is expanded to `0`, so `\ifnum\itemno=40\fi`. because `\itemno` isn't 40 then `\ifnum` expands to empty, so `\global\advance\itemno by 1<empty>` is executed now, it means the `\itemno` increments. And that is all. IMHO this was not the intention of the author. The second example is similar.

**Exercise**: what hapens when you type:

```
\newcount\itemno
\global\advance\itemno by 1%
\ifnum\itemno=4\the\itemno\fi
5
```

Answer: The `\itemno` increments by 15.

Answer (score 6):

You need an inverse egreg: don't put `%` at ends of lines.

```
\global\advance\itemno by 1
\ifnum\itemno=4 \the\itemno\fi
```

Otherwise the `\ifnum` is expanded while looking for the end of the number that starts with `1` before the assignment is done.

In addition,

```
\ifnum\itemno=4\the\itemno\fi
```

can never be true as if `\itemno`  is say 4 then it is equivalent to

```
\ifnum\itemno=44\fi
```

which will of course be false. hence the space after `4` in the above.

Comment: Or replace the `%` by a `\relax`?

Comment: @Jubobs If you like typing (and you are not in an expandable context where `\relax` will mess you up)

Comment: From the TeXbook, p. 208: For best results, *always put a blank space after a numeric constant*; this blank space tells TeX that the constant is complete, and such a space will never “get through” to the output.